# Prove theorem with series

Tags: coq

I'd like to prove a theorem on two sequences as

```
forall (a1,a2,...,an ∈ A), (b ∈ B) , (d1,d2,...,dn,d* ∈ D), 
a1+b=d1 AND a2+b=d2 AND ... AND an+b=dn AND ô(a1,a2,..,an)+b=d*  ->
          σ(d1,d2,...,dn) = d*
```

+,ô,σ are operators that are defined on inductive data types A,B,D. How should I code this theorem in Coq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `list` to write the theorem, and use pairs to get the same number of `A` as `D`:

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Goal forall (ad : list (A * D)) (b : B) (dstar : D),
  List.Forall (fun '(ai, di) => ai + b = dstar) ad
  /\ ô(List.map (@fst A D) ad) + b = dstar ->
    σ(List.map (@snd A B) ad) = dstar.
```

Comment: Thank you Jason. That's helpful.

Comment: After applying some customizations and trying to prove the theorem, I get this hypothesis in the context: H: Forall (fun '(pol_i, ans_i) => FinalDecision(Evaluation pol_i q) = ans_i) [(T, Used)]. I applied simpl or unfold tactics to make it as FinalDecision(Evaluation T q) = Used, but none of them works. So how should I reduce this kind of hypothesis? Thank you.

Comment: Try `inversion`

Comment: This works except for one case. When the hypothesis is : H: Forall (fun '(pol_i, ans_i) => pol_i <> nil /\ FinalDecision(Evaluation pol_i q) = ans_i)[] , that is when Listofpairs is equal to [ ] , I cannot reduce this hypothesis to False. Is there any way to reduce this expression to False? I used simpl and inversion H tactics with no change and Elim H adds another goal but nothing is added to help me prove current goal. Thank you.

Comment: Your hypothesis is true, so you cannot reduce it to `False`.  It's quite easy to prove `forall A P, Forall P (@nil A)` by `constructor`.